# Child Theme not loading multiple stylesheets

Tags: functions, css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I have little experience with creating a Child Theme.
Just want to make some changes to css on the website.

When I use the inspect mode to see which CSS was being used, I saw it was still linking to the parent css. Do I have the right code for my functions.php?

[image: function.php]

Answer (score 0):

The `get_template_directory_uri()` function returns the URL to the root theme.

If a child theme is used and you want to return the URL to the current child theme, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have replaced 'get_template_directory_uri()' with 'get_stylesheet_directory_uri()' but that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry. the source code through the link I didn't understand. Do I have to place it somewhere as well?

Comment: Hi you need to simply change `get_template_directory_uri` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is something to be added in the top of style.css (child) file. Have you written it ? If yes then ignore it. if not you will have to add these following lines.

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Theme Child   
 Description:  about_your_child_theme
 Author:       your_name
 Template:     name_of_your_parent_theme
 Version:      1.0.0
*/
```

The first and 4th one are so important (Theme name and Template). Make sure your Template name and parent theme are same